# ios remove trailing whitespace on switching between textfields by touching on screen

Tags: ios, uitextview

This might be very basic, but I'm new to iOS and I think I don't know the right keywords to search..

I've multiple UITextField's in my screen. I can remove the trailing white spaces in the textfield when touching the done button on the keyboard by using:

```
- (IBAction)firstNameDismiss:(id)sender {
    [firstnameTextField setText:[firstnameTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];
    [firstnameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But when I switch to another TextField by touching it(not touching Done button on keyboard of previous UITextField), trailing space is not getting removed.

Please help.

Comment: have a look at UITextFields _textFieldDidEndEditing_ and _textFieldShouldReturn_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look into the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol as documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/

Then you can use the `textFieldDidEndEditing` function to do the same as you're doing in your `firstNameDismiss:` function. You'll probably also want to implement the `textFieldShouldReturn:` function.

Comment: @Hodson THX that u repeat my comment ;-)

Comment: @UlliHeinelt: I didn't even see your comment when providing my answer and also my answer includes the delegate to use and documentation about it and the functions you mention in your comment. I suggest that in the future, if you want to answer a question, you write it as an answer and not a comment.